# PHP array : Echo a $var inside a form with option value

Tags: php, arrays, forms

How can I display variable $player->name inside a form option value so user could select variable and submit form.

Here's my code that is not working :

```
<?php
    $team = $_POST['team'];

    $result =        file_get_contents("http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/teamroster/$team/iphone/clubroster.j    son");
    $json = json_decode($result);
    $goalies = $json->goali;
    foreach ($json->goalie as $player) {

        **echo "<option value=\"".$player->name."\">".$player->name."</option>**
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is a `.j    son` file? Also, what do you mean by "not working"? Do you get any errors? If not then do you have errors turned off?

Comment: **echo this will throw error

Comment: @CodingAnt OP tried to highlight that line.

Comment: why do you have ** ? This will throw an error for sure. Next thing i see that you are assigning $json->goali to $goalies. Is that array? If its array, you can not access to variable with $player->name, but $player['name']. And of course you need to have <select> before php code you showed here.

Comment: Oh how we would know, OP could have used comment to higlight this @Ja͢ck

Comment: What is this $json->goalie value in foreach , use $goalies instead

Answer (score 2):

You did not have the double quotes and semicolon at the end of statement.

```
 <?php 
$team = $_POST['team'];
$result =    file_get_contents("http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/teamroster/$team/iphone/clubroster.json");
$json = json_decode($result);
$goalies = $json->goali;
foreach ($json->goalie as $player) {

    echo "<option value=\"".$player->name."\">".$player->name."</option>";
}
?>
```

Comment: If you are going to fix his code then you should at least put in some error checking.

Comment: true, at least the error is not displaying- I'm still trying to display the option value menu with multiple var inside. Do I need to add the form tag ? thanks

Comment: As the question, this code is an XSS waiting to happen.

Answer (score 2):

What is this `$json->goalie` value in `foreach` , use `$goalies` instead

```
<?php 
$team = $_POST['team'];
$result = file_get_contents("http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/teamroster/$team/iphone/clubroster.json");
$json = json_decode($result);
$goalies = $json->goali;
foreach ($goalies as $player) 
{          
    echo "<option value='".$player->name."'>".$player->name."</option>";
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens if the player name has an apostrophe?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the obvious parse error you have in your code, here are some other things to look out for:

```
$team = $_POST['team'];

$result = file_get_contents("http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/teamroster/$team/iphone/clubroster.json");
```

You can't just use `$team` inside a URL like that, you're supposed to **encode** it:

```
$url = sprintf("http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/teamroster/%s/iphone/clubroster.json",
    urlencode($team)
);

$result = file_get_contents($url);

$json = json_decode($result);
foreach ($json->goalie as $player) {
    echo "<option value=\"".$player->name."\">".$player->name."</option>";
}
```

You should always **escape** your variables in output:

```
    printf('<option value="%s">%1$s</option>',
        htmlspecialchars($player->name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display varibles inside string then always use "" for displaying the variable. You can modify your code as:

```
echo "<option value='{$player->name}'>{$player->name}</option>";
```

So always remember:
1. You can use ''(singlequots) inside ""(doublequotes)

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd recommend decoding your JSON to an array, not an object, it is easier to work with.
2. You aren't using the `goalies` variable in your above code, I'm assuming that's what you want to use in the `foreach` statement?
3. Error checking would be a good idea

If so, then your code may look something like this:

```
<?php
    $team = $_POST['team'];

    $result = file_get_contents("http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/teamroster/$team/iphone/clubroster.json");
    $json = json_decode($result, true);
    $goalies = array();
    if (!empty($json['goali'])) {
        $goalies = $json['goali'];
    }

    foreach ($goalies as $player) {
        echo '<option value="' . $player['name'] . '">' . $player['name'] . '</option>'
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not using the `'` correctly around your variables.

#### [Demo](http://ideone.com/D8R60Q)

```
<?php

// Create a dummy Object
$player = new stdClass();

// Create a dummy property
$player->name = "Occam's Razor";

// Print it out
echo '<option value=" '.htmlspecialchars($player->name).' ">' .htmlspecialchars($player->name). '</option>';
```

This prints out the following.

`<option value=" Occam's Razor ">Occam's Razor</option>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing about what the problem is, I think it would be more helpful to just show you, and give you some pointers:

```
// Make sure all errors are displayed
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Get the team variable and make sure that it was set
$team = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'team', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);
if ($team === null) {
    die('Error: The "team" POST variable is not set, cannot continue');
}
// Since you are using the variable inside a URL it makes
// sense to remove potentially unsafe characters; or in
// other words, only preserve characters that are allowed.
// Encoding the variable, as in Ja͢ck's answer, is also an option.
$team = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/', null, $team);
if ($team === "") {
    die('Error: The "team" variable is empty, cannot continue');
}
// Construct the URL
$url = "http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/teamroster/{$team}/iphone/clubroster.json";

// Grab the data from the website
$data = file_get_contents($url);
if ($data === false) {
    die('Error: Could not grab the data from the URL, cannot continue');
}
// Attempt to decode the data
$json = json_decode($data);
if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    die('Error: There was a JSON error ('.json_last_error_msg().'), cannot continue');
}
// Since we are expecting an object we should check for it
// before using it
if ( ! is_object($json)) {
    die('Error: The JSON was decoded, but is not an object, cannot use it...');
}
// If the following code gives you problems then read the error
// message, try to understand what it says, and then google it if
// you are getting nowhere
$goalies = $json->goali;
foreach ($json->goalie as $player) {
    echo "<option value=\"".$player->name."\">".$player->name."</option>";
}
```

Comment: Where's the output escaping?

Comment: @Ja͢ck I did not touch the last few lines. The problem was with not checking for errors. The safety of the output is for another time.